# Prevent Mat-chip from adding row after selection

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material, material-ui

I am trying to prevent the mat-chip module from automatically adding a row after one chip has been selected. The max chip count is 1, so I disable the input after the user selects an item from the dropdown. But, it still adds a row beneath it as if they can type more. How can I prevent that?

[image: chip input]

```
  <mat-chip-list #chipList aria-label="Fruit selection"  >
    <mat-chip
      *ngFor="let item of selected; let i = index"
      [selectable]="!disabled"
      [removable]="!disabled"
      (removed)="remove(i)">
      {{item[filterProperty]}}
      <mat-icon matChipRemove>cancel</mat-icon>
    </mat-chip>
    <input
    [maxLength]="maxLength"
      [value]="optionBaseValue"
      [placeholder]="label" #chipsInput
      [disabled]="(selected.length === maxCount) || inEditMode === false"
      [matAutocomplete]="auto"
      [matChipInputFor]="chipList"
      [matChipInputSeparatorKeyCodes]="separatorKeysCodes"
      [matChipInputAddOnBlur]="addOnBlur"
      (focus)="autoInputValue($event)"
      (focusout)="resetAutoInputValue($event)"
      (matChipInputTokenEnd)="add($event)">
  </mat-chip-list>
  <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" (optionSelected)="itemSelected($event)" (onBlur)="itemSelected($event)">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let item of filteredItems | async " [value]="item">
      <div > {{item[filterProperty]}}</div>
    </mat-option>
  </mat-autocomplete>
```

Thank you!!

Comment: something like `<input [hidden]="selected.length === 1"` perhaps?

Comment: Does this resolve the issue?

Comment: yes thank you! just changed the condition to be >0. Works well

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like:

```html
<input [hidden]="selected.length === 1"
```

Note that you can change the conditional however you like.